# C#7 safeguard for deconstruction?

Tags: tuples, c#-7.0

Is there a way to protect oneself from side effect to deconstruction when rearrenging elements' ordering in a tuple value?

For instance, the second console's writeline would output the wrong results.

```
    public void Test()
    {
        var result = GetResult(10, 5);
        Console.WriteLine($"sum: {result.sum}, substraction : {result.substraction}");


        (int substraction, int sum) = result;
        Console.WriteLine($"sum: {sum}, substraction : {substraction}");

    }

    //Old version
    //private (int substraction, int sum) GetResult(int a, int b) => (a - b, a + b);
    private (int sum, int substraction) GetResult(int a, int b) => (a + b, a - b);
```

Comment: I don't know... maybe pay attention to the actual return type? Even if you were to declare the variables that way, the return type will still provide the correct names. That's no different than trying to protect someone from writing something like `var sum = a - b;`.

Comment: How would you do that with `Tuple` or any other class for that matter? `(int substraction, int sum) = result;` extracts field values and places them in variables with the names you provided. The variable names could be anything.

Comment: A Roslyn code analyzer could check for shuffled names, ignoring cases where the names don't match (because you probably *did* want to use different names). ReSharper offers tuple name checking

Answer (score 1):

> **"Element names are semantically insignificant except when used directly."**

(From ["C# Tuples. More about element names"](http://mustoverride.com/tuples_names/), by Vladimir Sadov who is a member of the C# language team).

Except in a few cases (as Vladimir explains in his post), the element names are ignored by the compiler unless explicitly accessed. This isn't just limited to deconstruction. The following code compiles just fine:

```
void Example()
{
    (int a, int b) GetTuple() => (1, 2);
    void PrintTuple((int b, int a) t) => Console.WriteLine($"a:{t.a}, b:{t.b}");

    var t = GetTuple();
    PrintTuple(t);
}
```

And the output is `a:2, b:1`.

So the compiler itself offers you no protection against mismatching names in tuples and deconstructions. That's not to say no protection is possible, it just needs someone (eg you) to write a Roslyn analyzer that detects name swaps like this and reports it as a warning.

Answer (score 0):

This feature (warning for element names mismatches that are clearly accidental) did not make it into C# 7.0. You can voice your interest and follow the progress at https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/14217

It is also possible that some analyzers will fill this gap.

Note this sort of accident is not unique to tuples or deconstruction, you can accidentally pass arguments in the wrong order in invocations (in or out parameters).